# Pi Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, package-management

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution  
Reading package lists... Done  
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success '/usr/bin/test -e /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.PackageKit.service && /usr/bin/test -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket && /usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.PackageKit --object-path /org/freedesktop/PackageKit --timeout 4 --method org.freedesktop.PackageKit.StateHasChanged cache-update > /dev/null; /bin/echo >`/der/null'
```

I believe the issue is that there is a back tick  by der/null but I do not know where to fix it.

Comment: **Pi Problem**: Is it Raspberry Pi? Which OS is it using?

Comment: There is a `\`/der/null` at the end that causes the problem, and should be `/dev/null` anyway.